# Libcurl - What does "curl_multi_perform"

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to understand how curl_multi_perform works.
The documentation says that:

> This function performs transfers on all the added handles that need
> attention in an non-blocking fashion. The easy handles have previously
> been added to the multi handle with curl_multi_add_handle.
>
> When an application has found out there's data available for the
> multi_handle or a timeout has elapsed, the **application should call**
> this function to read/write whatever there is to read or write right
> now etc.

Question 1: What does the "application should call" mean? How can an application cause something? Did you mean the programmer should call ?

OK, I found two simple usage examples - "curl_multi_perform":

1 - https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/drive/multi

```
int transfers_running;
do {
   curl_multi_wait ( multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
   curl_multi_perform ( multi_handle, &transfers_running );
} while (transfers_running);
```

2 - [enter link description here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html)

```
int still_running;
do {
  CURLMcode mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
 
  if(!mc && still_running)
    /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
    mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
 
  if(mc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_multi_poll() failed, code %d.\n", (int)mc);
    break;
  }
 
/* if there are still transfers, loop! */
} while(still_running);
```

-Firstly:

- in the first example curl_multi_perform is called after curl_multi_wait.
- in the second example curl_multi_perform is called before curl_multi_wait.

Nothing is clear.

- Secondly:

Why do I need to call curl_multi_perform in a loop ?? I do not understand.

Why is one call not enough ?

Comment: The application is the code that the programmer has written.

Comment: @Barmar, and why is curl_multi_perform called in different examples in different parts of the loop and why is it called in the loop at all ?

Comment: As the documentation says, it's used to perform the data transfers on all the handles that are ready to read or write.

Comment: @Barmar, why is curl_multi_perform called in different examples in different parts of the loop and why is it called in the loop at all ?

Comment: So you have several transfers running, e.g. parallel downloads. Such programs wait most of the time for data to become available again. As soon as this is signaled, you can read and process data again. Then you wait again. During the waiting time you can e.g. update the user interface with the progress. curl_multi_perform returns as soon as the read/write operations are completed. It can also be called when there is no data to be transferred. Then the function returns immediately. Therefore the transfer is done in a loop. This offers a user e.g. also the possibility to cancel the transfer.

Comment: It is important to understand that curl_multi_perform does **not** transfer all data and return when all data has been transferred. Instead, it transfers only the portion of the data that is available at that time.

Comment: @Stephan Schlecht, thank you, but, why is curl_multi_perform called in different examples in different parts of the loop ?

Comment: The order does not matter, since curl_multi_perform can also be called when there is no data to be transferred and the two calls are executed in a loop anyway. However, it makes sense to have curl_multi_wait or curl_multi_poll in the loop, so that there is not a high, completely unnecessary CPU load caused by the loop, since you are actually just waiting most of the time for data to be available again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: What does the "application should call" mean? How can an application cause something? Did you mean the programmer should call ?

Programmers don't call functions. Programmers write programs that tell the computer what to do. So this means that the programmer should write code that tells the application to call the function.

> - in the first example curl_multi_perform is called after curl_multi_wait.
> - in the second example curl_multi_perform is called before curl_multi_wait.

Either order works. As the documentation says:

> This function does not require that there actually is any data available for reading or that data can be written, it can be called just in case.

If there's nothing available, it will simply return immediately, updating `transfers_running`.

> Why do I need to call curl_multi_perform in a loop ?? I do not understand.

Because multiple transfers are in progress. `curl_multi_wait()` returns as soon as data is available on any of them. After you process that data, you need to continue waiting for other transfers.

Also, this doesn't wait for transfers to be complete, it processes partial data as it arrives. So you have to keep calling it until you've sent or received everything.

Comment: But then why isn 't curl_easy_perform also called in the loop ? Why is it enough to call curl_easy_perform only once ?

Comment: `curl_easy_perform()` just processes one curl handle completely, it doesn't need to deal with multiple curl handles that have data at different times.

Comment: `curl_easy_perform()` does the entire (single) transfer in a blocking call. The multi interface is non-blocking.